# Set the position of a button in a layout via Java

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm currently working on a game that has buttons changing positions. I was wondering how I could change the buttons position in a GridLayout via java code

Comment: Did you google this? What is still unclear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just simply change the X and Y.

```
Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.YourButtonIDInXML);
myButton.setX(<x value>);
myButton.setY(<y value>);
```

Comment: Accept the answer. Help a my interest in helping other grow by stackoverlow points. @gummy714